# select option depending on some condition

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, select

I have combobox:

```
<select name="studstatus">
    <option></option> 
    <option>flunked</option> 
    <option >abiturient</option> 
    <option >bachelor</option> 
    <option >magistrant</option> 
    <option>aspirant</option> 
    <option>graduated</option> 
</select>
```

and i have some bean I want that as default option select my bean value. How can I do that?

Comment: Code please. What is a combo box? Does this help?http://www.devsphere.com/mapping/docs/guide/simple.html

Comment: <select  name="studstatus"> 
 <option></option>
 <option>flunked</option>
 <option >abiturient</option>
 <option >bachelor</option>
 <option >magistrant</option>
 <option>aspirant</option>
 <option>graduated</option>
  </select>

Comment: I know how do with bean and it could be be some string it doensn't matter. I want to know how to select combobox default value depending on some condition.

Comment: `<option <%= selected ? "SELECTED" : "" %>>`

Comment: I wish I could downvote comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be the wanted answer

```
<option <%= selected ? "SELECTED" : "" %>>
```

or

```
<option <c:if test="${something == something}">SELECTED</c:if> >...
```

Comment: Yes, but I do with jstl <c:if> instead of scriplet.